# Selenium WebDriver with Java: Can't accept alert

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

When recording in selenium IDE I can click the "OK" button in a popup, and expected to be able to click it using

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("OK")).click();
```

but this was not the case.

Similarly this doesn't work.

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Selenium throws a NoAlertPresent exception. If what's popping up is not an alert, then what is it? And how do I click yes!

Comment: Is it an actual Javascript confirmation? If it isn't, then the `IAlert` interface you are calling by doing `.alert()` won't help you.

Comment: As it's not Alert no need the line of code: driver.switchTo().alert().accept();

Answer (score 2):

It could be anything. You should be telling us that.

If it is a Java Script alert then, this should work

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

At the very least you could try sending enter/return key stroke, if the "OK" button is autoselected/highlighted by the web app.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys
WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

**Update**

---

It could also be because your alert is not present at the time you are trying to click/accept it. 
For a *quick* check put in a sleep of 4-5 seconds and then try `driver.switchTo().alert().accept();`. Once it is ascertained, then put in a wait for alert present in a `try` and `catch` loop (any exception handling).

Comment: I'm new to the whole automation deal. However I have also tried your idea of Keys.return to no avail. All I know for certain is that the line driver.switchto().alert.accept() has worked for me on other applications. This is why I'm confused that it's not working here.

Comment: do you have firebug(firefox add on) installed? if no download it. Using that addon, right click on that "ok" button of the popup/alert and select inspect with firebug.

Answer (score 2):

in such case I'd prefer to check(verify) the alert presence on the page and then if is present - accept it.
It be somthing like:

```
public boolean isAlertPresent() {

  boolean presentFlag = false;

  try {

   // Check the presence of alert
   Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
   // Alert present; set the flag
   presentFlag = true;
   // if present consume the alert
   alert.accept();

  } catch (NoAlertPresentException ex) {
   // Alert not present
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }

  return presentFlag;

 }
```

[here](http://seleniumwebdriverfaq.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-check-presence-of-alert.html) you can get details
Also do not forget about debug step by step.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using latest version of webdriver, infact anything above 2.20 then

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

should work provided the alert is a javascript alert similar to the one we get when we click

[alert demo](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert) OR [confirm pop-up demo](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_confirm)

**Updated**

here this code will help you accept the alert

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
String baseUrl = "http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert";
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get(baseUrl);
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"button\"]")).click();
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Comment: I don't understand. I would of thought that performing the action is what generates the alert, so how then could I switch to the alert before performing the action?

Comment: Sorry I typed wrong alert should be accepted just after the action. Updated the answer.