# Alert Handling in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I tried to switch to popup alert and click on OK button, but i got an error saying that xpath (for OK button) is not found.

But this is working for me sometimes using the same code. Could anyone help me out on this. I tried all possible ways that is available in blogs. But i couldn't make it

Comment: Please post the code you are using with any errors, etc. along with a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244723/alert-handling-in-selenium-webdriver-selenium-2-with-java

Comment: I could able to get the answer from the following link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893478/selenium-webdriver-with-java-cant-accept-alert

As the code is not identifying the popup alert. I tried using Keys.ENTER to click on OK button. It worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the original question and the subsequent comments, I suspect what you're dealing with is a browser pop up window and not an alert. So this won't work

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

You need to use window handles

```
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); 
Iterator<String> windows = handles.iterator(); 
String parent = windows.next(); 
String child = windows.next();
driver.switchTo().window(child);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("insert xpath to OK button")).click();
driver.switchTo().window(parent);
//continue with steps on parent window
```

Note: ensure that you add the required synchronization to the code snippet above

Comment: I agree that it's not an Alert but it's likely not a new window either. It sounds like a simple DIV popup.

Comment: True. In which case the solution would be to simply wait for the ok button and click on it. But there isn't much info to go by.

Comment: Agreed. We, as a community, need to be more insistent on requiring basic facts before we start answering questions. We will get better questions, better answers, and spend a lot less time wasting time on questions with no info that will likely never be fixed into good questions.

Answer (score 2):

you need to move control to your pop-up window first before doing any operation on pop-up window:-

below code is to move selenium control on pop-up window

```
driver.switchTo().alert();
```

by writing below line

```
alert.accept();
```

alert will get close

Comment: 2nd line 'alert.accept();' will close the alert correct?

Comment: I used 1st line and driver.switchTo().alert(); and i gave the xpath for OK button but still it is not identifying the popup alert

Comment: I got an error like

No alert is present (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: yes surely. It will work fine. you can refer below link. https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-handle-javascript-alerts-confirmation-prompts

Comment: no need to give xpath for OK button, if it is alert it will work.

Comment: @Meghasri Is it a javascript alert popup or something like a div made visible?

Comment: actually the problem is, when i give 'driver.switchTo().alert();' then i could see the system is not identifiying it as alert at all. Any other solution :( ??

Comment: Actual format for a popup should be something like this correct?
        <script>
 function myFunction()
 {
 confirm("Press a button!");
 }
 </script>

But in my html code the format is different

        <tr>
        <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
       <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
      <a class="prefix-TextButton orange" href="javascript:void(0)"     style="width: 15px;">OK</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>